# divide matrix to blocks with parallel diagonal lines

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a problem. I want to divide an Image to blocks with (45 and -45) degree parallel diagonal lines.
can you help me how I should trace my pixels matrix?"

I tried to write some codes for this method. I divide a matrix that width and height are equal. to two triangle. you know (i,j ) = (0,0) is at left top of image matrix, so until the diagonal is one triangle and after that is other.
here is my code.

```
public static int[] getBlackNo_45Degree(int[][] pixels, int sectionNo){
        int height = pixels.length;
        int width = pixels[0].length;
        System.out.println(width +" - " +height);
        int [] blackNo_Diagonal = new int[sectionNo];
        int section = (height / sectionNo )* 2;
        int temp =0, index = section, blackNo = 0, arrayIn =0;

        for(int count= 0 ; count<sectionNo/2 ; count++){
            blackNo = 0;
            for(int row = temp; row< index ; row++ ){
                int rowIndex = row ;
                for(int col= 0 ; col <= row ; col++){
            //      System.out.println("row-col :"+rowIndex +"-"+col);
                    int rgb = pixels[rowIndex --][col];

                    if(rgb == Color.BLACK.getRGB())
                        blackNo ++;

                }
            }
            blackNo_Diagonal[arrayIn++]= blackNo;
            temp += section;
            index += section;
            System.out.println(blackNo);
        }
        temp = 0;
        index = section;
        for(int count= 0 ; count<sectionNo  /2 ; count++){
            blackNo = 0;
            for(int col= temp +1 ; col <= index  ; col++){
                int colIndex = col;
                for(int row= (height -1) ; colIndex < width ; row--){
                //System.out.println("row-col :"+row +"-"+colIndex);
                    int rgb = pixels[row][colIndex++];
                    if(rgb == Color.BLACK.getRGB())
                        blackNo ++;


                } 
            }
            blackNo_Diagonal[arrayIn++]= blackNo;
            temp += section;
            index += section;
            System.out.println(blackNo);
        }
        return  blackNo_Diagonal;
    }
```

I wrote this, but this is not very efficient.what is your idea about? 
for the first compile, i tried a little matrix not an Image. here is the sample matrix and output of method (sectionNo == 4):

```
    int[][] pixels ={{Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB()},
                     {Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB(),Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.black.getRGB()},
                     {Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB()},
                     {Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.white.getRGB(),Color.BLACK.getRGB(),Color.black.getRGB()}

    };
```

output :

```
row-col :0-0
row-col :1-0
row-col :0-1
3
row-col :2-0
row-col :1-1
row-col :0-2
row-col :3-0
row-col :2-1
row-col :1-2
row-col :0-3
4
row-col :3-1
row-col :2-2
row-col :1-3
row-col :3-2
row-col :2-3
2
row-col :3-3
1
```

Comment: *"can you help me how I should trace my pixels matrix?"*  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)   For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your attempt (hot-link to an image).

Comment: I edit my question please read it again.